# How to process/fetch data concurrently in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, concurrency

I'm working on a project which for optimization/scalability reasons am trying to fetch data from an api, and then process this data (add a node to a graph) and then while its processing, start fetching for the next piece of data. I have this data in a list, and initially I thought maybe I could do this using a for loop but realized that before all the data is fetched, it iterates through the for loop and basically ends up messing up the processing. I thought maybe I could do this using some sort of asynchronous for loop where it waits for the processing to begin to continue, but was wondering if there was a more standard way to accomplish this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) library in your browser.

You have to add this script:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.1.0/q.js"></script>`

With this library you will have `.all()` function that allow you to run multiple async function and to know that all of them finished.

[here](http://www.willvillanueva.com/introducing-q-all-in-promises/) you have some examples.